# Using the Comment Plugin with an iFrame App

Tags: plugins, facebook-iframe, facebook-comments, iframe-app

I'm trying to create an iFrame application with some static content and a comment 'wall', where users can contribute to a discussion on the topic of the app.

I've used the Comments Plugin like so:

within the code of the application page (/appfolder/index.php):

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.clientwebsite.com/appfolder/share.html" data-colorscheme="light" data-num-posts="20" data-width="510"></div>
```

Note: share.html is a small page containing META information such as the user accounts of the admins who need to be able to moderate comments, a page title, description, and a redirect command which points back to the actual facebook.com/BrandPage?sk=appidxxxxxx

I've defined the appId in share.html, and this gives me access to the full moderation set (so I think), but my problem is that I cannot find any settings for allowing users' posts to display for all users by default.

The documentation for the plugin says:
"Admins can choose to make the default for new comments entered either “visible to everyone” or “has limited visibility” on the site (i.e., the comment is only visible to the commenter and their friends), to help mitigate irrelevant content."

When I post comments as a test user on the app, they don't show up when I log back in as a developer, nor visa-versa. It seems users can only see comments THEY posted.

WHERE Can I adjust this setting? Is it unavailable due to the way I'm using the comment plugin (Iframe app?)

Thanks in advance..

Comment: found bug report: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/141490292621085/?browse=search_4ef108cc6c0104b67979008

But unclear whether this will solve the issue of not being able to see comments left by other FB users.

Comment: can you clarify what you mean by "test users"? If you are using **real** test users - you should know that they operate in a sort of "sandbox" and no action made by a test user can be seen by regular users and vice versa.

Comment: That's the issue here. If you want to post that as an answer I'll wrap things up here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here seems to be the limitations of test users; Specifically that actions performed by test uses are only visible to other test users.  They exist in their own *sandbox*.

Here are a list of relevant limitations taken from the [Facebook documentation on test users](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/test_users/)  -

> - Test users can interact with other test users only and not with real
>     users on site.
> - Test users cannot fan a public Page or create public
>     content on them like writing on a Page's wall. A Test user can however
>     view and interact with the app tab on the Page if they are associated
>     with that app.
> - They can be accessed and used by any developer of the
>     associated app.
> - They only have test privileges on the associated app.
>     This implies that they can use the app in live mode or sandbox mode
>     but cannot edit any technical settings or access insights for that
>     app.